# How to structure models for forecasting app?

Tags: python, django, django-models

In Django, I am looking for recommendations on how to structure models for a forecasting app that is similar to a polling or quiz app - but not quite.

Overview of requirements:

(1) A quiz will have multiple questions.

(2) Questions can take multiple forms - True or False, Multiple Choice with 3 options, Multiple choice with 4 options, etc.

(3) Users submit forecasts (aka answers) for each question in the form of probabilities with the constraint that the total probability is 100%. So, for question #1 with three options A-C a user might forecast A: 30%, B: 50%, C: 20%

(4) Each question has 1 correct answer.

[Questions are scored using Brier scoring, but that is not essential for this discussion.]

I am familiar with the Django tutorial polling app and have looked at multiple quiz apps, but none of them address my problem.

If I use the structure of the Django polling tutorial with the number of choices being indeterminate, then I can't figure out how organize a user's forecast to a question - since that forecast must have a probability for each choice and the probabilities must add up to 100%.

If I create multiple models of questions, like TrueFalseQuestion, MultipleChoice3OptionsQuestion, etc then my views and templates become unwieldy since I can't just set context to Question model.

I considered creating a parent class Question with abstract=True and then creating children classes like "class TFQuestion(Question):". But, again this makes my ability to use generic templates like ListView limited, since I now have many children classes.

To summarize, what makes my problem different from everything else that I can find is: Most quiz apps have a User provide a single choice among multiple choices, no matter how many choices. My app requires an answer (forecast) that consists of a probability for each choice option, along with the constraint that probabilities equal 100%.

************* ADDING MORE DETAIL BELOW *************

To simplify, lets assume that I want every question to have 3 multiple choice options. In this case, every user forecast will consist of a set of 3 probabilities and a comment.

First question: Is there a better way to structure the models below for the case of 3 answer options?

```py
class Quiz(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Question(model.Model):
   quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   choice1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   choice2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   choice3 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   correct_choice = models.IntegerField()

class Forecast(model.Model):
   question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   comment = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   prob1 = models.IntegerField()
   prob2 = models.IntegerField()
   prob3 = models.IntegerField()
```

If this is a good structure for questions with 3 options, then how would I extend this to my original requirements of having questions with 2, 3, 4, 5 options?

My issue is that if I use the structure in the Django tutorial polling app, where the number of choices is indeterminate - then my Forecast model above breaks since it has hard-coded 3 options.

Comment: I think your question is too broad to get relevant answers. It almost looks like you are putting here your requirements expecting someone would write a django-model for you. Instead, start to draft your models, their relationships, and then ask narrower questions.

To help you getting started, if you update your question with your django models, i'd be happy to review and provide help if you struggle somewhere.

Comment: also, I would consider adding the django-model tag and removing postgresql as your question is not directly relevant to the database backend

Comment: @alfjet - Thank you so much for weighing in. If it is not obvious, I'm new to web development. In the post above I edited it to consider a simplified case of questions with 3 options. I'm curious to hear any advise on the structure of this. And, ultimately  how I'd structure the case of questions with different numbers of options. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a structure like this would work for you (with true-false questions being modeled as 2-choice questions):

```py
class Quiz(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Question(model.Model):
   quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   correct_choice = models.ForeignKey('Choice')


class Choice(model.Model):
   question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   text = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Forecast(model.Model):
   question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   comment = models.CharField(max_length=200)

   class Meta:
       unique_together = (('question', 'user'),)


class ForecastChoice(model.Model):
   forecast = models.ForeignKey(Forecast, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   choice = models.ForeignKey(Choice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   probability = models.IntegerField()

   class Meta:
       unique_together = (('forecast', 'choice'),)
```

The constraints not modelable with `unique_together` are left as an exercise for the reader:

- a Forecast must end up with as many ForecastChoices as there are Choices in the Question
- a Forecast's ForecastChoices' probabilities must sum up to 100

You will probably also want an `ordering` field for Questions, if that matters here, as well as the usual metadata such as creation time for `Forecast`s.

*EDIT* As requested in the comments, an example of a `ForecastForm` that has dynamically created probability fields for each choice and a view to drive it.  It's dry-coded, so there may be silly mistakes, but the idea is solid.

```py
class ForecastForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Forecast
        fields = ('comment',)  # tell Django to only create this field

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        # Build dynamic fields.
        self.probability_fields = []
        for choice in self.instance.question.choice_set.all():
            name = f'probability_{choice.id}'
            field = forms.IntegerField(
                label=f'{choice.text} – probability',
                min_value=0,
                max_value=100,
                required=True,
            )
            # Put the field in the form...
            self.fields[name] = field
            # ... and store the name + choice object for later validation use
            self.probability_fields.append((name, choice))

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        probability_sum = 0
        for name, choice in self.probability_fields:
            probability = self.cleaned_data[name]
            probability_sum += probability
        if probability_sum != 100:
            raise forms.ValidationError(f'Probabilities sum up to {probability_sum}, not the expected 100.')

    def save(self):
        with transaction.atomic():
            super().save()  # will save the `self.instance` Forecast object with the comment
            for name, choice in self.probability_fields:
                ForecastChoice.objects.create(
                    forecast=self.instance,
                    choice=choice,
                    probability=self.cleaned_data[name],
                )

# This is a slightly unorthodox updateview in that the form it's driving
# is not directly related to the model the underlying "detail view" is acquiring.

class QuestionForecastView(views.UpdateView):
    model = Question

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        # Unsaved forecast initialized with the question and user context.
        forecast = Forecast(
            question=self.get_object(),
            user=self.request.user,
        )
        kwargs = self.get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['instance'] = instance
        return ForecastForm(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate the recommendation. I need some time to think through how to impose the constraints in this structure, but getting pointed in the right direction helps tremendously.

Comment: The constraints aren't hard to implement in `save()`/`clean()` functions, or in the forms you'll accept the data with.

Comment: I've attempted to implement the structure above, but I'm running into trouble with creating a ForecastForm. A ForecastForm should have a comment input as well as probability input for each question choice, so there will be multiple objects created - a Forecast and a ForecastChoice object for every choice. I can't seem to find an analogy out there. Any recommendation on an example I could look at? FWIW, I did read up on save()/clean() and how I can implement the constraints. That makes sense. It feels like I'm doing something wrong with the form. Any advise would be much appreciated!

Comment: I can find examples of forms where there is a single known Foreign key relationship, like between a book and publisher. However, I haven't yet found an example of forms where there is an indeterminate number of Foreign key relationships as is the case above with ForecastChoice. I'm new and might be missing something obvious here.

Comment: Thank you AKX. I really appreciate it. I'll bang my head on this for a couple days and let you what comes of it.

Comment: @TomL: No worries. Just a heads-up though, I just changed how the view initializes the form so it actually works with POSTing too...